# Assign a random value to a dataframe column based on the values in an existing column

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to populate the Assignment column of my dataframe with a value from the employee column. I have pasted in example assignment values in the table below.
The assignment value can not equal the value that lives in the manager or subordinate column for that row. The assignment values also should not repeat.  Using the example, since Sue and Mary already been assigned they should no longer be available for assignment.

I found these instructions for [how to do something similar in excel](https://exceljet.net/formula/random-value-from-list-or-table) and this post on [generating a value from a random number with exclusions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42999093/generate-random-number-in-range-excluding-some-numbers/42999212), but I am stuck on how to do the intermediate steps in python.

```
+----------+---------+-------------+-------------------+----------------------------------------+
| Employee | Manager | Subordinate | Manager Exclusion | Subordinate Exclusion   |  Assignment  |
+----------+---------+-------------+-------------------+----------------------------------------+
| Jim      | Joe     |             |                 2 |                         |      Mary    |
| Joe      |         | Jim         |                   |                    1    |      Sue     |
| Sue      |         | David       |                   |                    5    |              |
| Kelly    | David   |             |                 5 |                         |              |
| David    | Sue     | Kelly       |                 3 |                    4    |              |
| Mary     | Jim     |             |                 1 |                         |              |
+----------+---------+-------------+-------------------+----------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Hi Meghan, welcome to StackOverflow! When asking questions it is usually good to include some code that you have tried. Reading through https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask is a good way to understand what types of questions will be well-received here.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do this with loops and the 'random' function. Seems like there are probably more efficient ways, but this is fast enough for a short list:

```
import pandas as pd
import random 
import numpy as np

#Create the data above

data = {
        'Employee':['Jim','Joe','Sue','Kelly','David','Mary'],
        'Manager':['Joe','','','David','Sue','Jim'],
        'Subordinate':['','Jim','David','','Kelly',''] }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

#Create list to store 'used' assignments
used = []

#Make blank column for the Assignments

df['Assigned'] = ''

#Loop through the dataframe
for index,row in df.iterrows(): 
#Iterate through random choices until it chooses one that meets the criteria
    while df.iat[index,3] == '':
        rname =  random.choice(df['Employee']) #Get random name from column 1
        if (rname != row['Manager']) and (rname != row['Subordinate']) and (rname != row['Employee']) and (rname not in used):
            df.iat[index,3] = rname #If it met the criteria, assign it.
            used.append(rname) #Add to 'used' list so it won't be used again
```