# Extract text and compare cells from table - python docx

Tags: python, python-docx

I have a program which prints random value from a list in the cells of a table using python docx.
The number of tables, cells and rows depend on user input.
I need to compare cells of tables before inputing value in the same number cell in another table.

For example.

```
number_of_tables = 5 #input by user
number_of_rows = 4 #input by user
number_of_cols = 7 #input by user

list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']

docu = Document()

for tablenum in range(number_of_tables):
    tablename = docu.add_table(rows = number_of_rows, cols = number_of_cols)
    for rowiteration in tablename.rows[0:]:
        for cells in rowiteration.cells:
            cells.text = random.choices(list)
```

If here cell(0,0) in table 1 has 'a' I don't want to print in 'a' in cell(0,0) of table 2 and further more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you want to chose a random value from the `list`, but exclude one (or more) value(s) - see also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42999093/generate-random-number-in-range-excluding-some-numbers/42999212).

You should therefore construct another list without the value(s) that you want to exclude - example to exclude the value `'a'` from the choice:

```
random.choice([s for s in list if s != 'a'])
```

For your scenario, you will have to exclude all values from the same cell `(r,c)` in the other tables like this:

```
for tablenum in range(number_of_tables):
  tablename = docu.add_table(rows=number_of_rows, cols=number_of_cols)
  for r, rowiteration in enumerate(tablename.rows):
    for c, cells in enumerate(rowiteration.cells):
      exclude = [docu.tables[num].cell(r,c).text for num in range(tablenum)]
      cells.text = random.choice([s for s in list if s not in exclude])
```

Comment: Thanks. I could extract previous table from docu but was struggling to point/extract particular cell in that table to compare with current table cell.