# How to get random index of the array without current idx?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, probability

I'm iterating over a list (numpy array with one dimension to be exact) and I need to pick an index form this list that is random and different than current iterator.

The most important thing is **constant and equal probability** over the range.

```py
list = ['a','b','c','d']
for idx , e in enumerate(list):
  return random.randrange(len(list)-1) # but without possibility of geting idx
```

-- EDIT --
Wouldnt that work:

```py
    x = np.array([1,2,3,4])
    for idx, e in enumerate(x):
        l = list(range(0, len(x)))
        l.pop(idx)
        res = random.choice(l)
        print(idx, res)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generate random number in range excluding some numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42999093/generate-random-number-in-range-excluding-some-numbers)

Comment: Honestly your answer below looks better. But it still destroys probability distribution. I think. Maybe to rephrase it would be better to select a value from a list of all indexes without the one. using `random.choice()`

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how large the list is, the chance of accidentally hitting idx might be small enough. So I usually do something like this:

```py
def randrange(n, without=None):
    while True:
        s = random.randrange(n)
        if s != without:
            return s
```

To use it, just replace your return statement with `return randrange(len(list)-1, idx)`

Comment: Thank you, I will do that if there is no better solution. :D

Answer (score 0):

You could try using

```py
list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
for idx, e in enumerate(list):
    temp = math.randrange(0, len(list)) # You would use -1, if it was randint()
    while temp == idx:
        temp = math.randrange(0, len(list))
    return temp
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you add an if statement to check whether the random number you get is different from the iterator?

```
import random

list1 = ['a','b','c','d']
for idx, e in enumerate(list1):
   randnum = random.randrange(len(list1)-1)
if randnum != idx:
    return randnum
```

One more advice: since the `list` library is reserved by python. better not use it as a variable name.